# Ruby error trying to set the datetime field in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm using rails 4.0.0, ruby 2.2.0
Trying to set the datetime field in one of the table in MySQL server I'm observing following error. Can any one suggest whats the issue.

```
    2.2.0 :048 > hm.start_time = "2014-03-12 14:45:00"
    NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:287:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/zones.rb:8:in `in_time_zone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:37:in `start_time='
    from (irb):48
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:34:in `require'
    from bin/rails:34:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try this: `hm.start_time = DateTime.parse("2014-03-12 14:45:00")` (by the way your value does not include any information about the Time Zone, it might be a problem)

Comment: hm is a Active Model object here, DateTime.parse fixed the issue. How can I avoid the specification of Time Zone info in the value.

Comment: Any solution on this? Getting same error when doing `MyMode.create(permitted_params)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime.parse("2014-03-12 14:45:00") as suggested by MrYoshiji. And for avoiding time zone issues you can specify in application.rb a setting:

```
config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

The database MySQL for example always stores the time in GMT but the rails will extract the date time in your specified time zone i.e., it will automatically convert it. Hope this helps.